# scanf() is not working in Thread

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, unix

I've to get input from Dispatched `Thread` and do some calculations on it. I'm facing issue while getting input from thread using `scanf()` of `stdio.h`.
console does not prompt for the input. Here is my code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void* square(){
    puts("\nfirst line of child\n");    
    int input,i=0;
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&input);
    do{
        scanf("%d",&i);
    }while(i!=0);
    printf("\ninput is %d\n",input);
    puts("\nlast line of child\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(void){
    puts("\nI'm Parent & I'm Starting\n");
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t pthread_attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&pthread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&pthread_attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pid_t tid = pthread_create(&thread,& pthread_attr,square,NULL);
    puts("\nI'm Parent & I'm going to exit\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tried `fflush(stdin)` to flush input stream but this also failed to help me.

Out I'm getting is (this does not execute the line of input).

```
I'm Parent & I'm Starting


I'm Parent & I'm going to exit


first line of child

first line of child`
```

Comment: When `main` exits, it takes the whole process with it, that includes killing any threads that might be running.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)`  From where did you pick this up?This causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: i though the failed input was because of "newline" in input stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the:

```
    fflush(stdin);
```

and make these changes to main:

```
    pthread_create(&thread,&pthread_attr,square,NULL);
    (void)pthread_join(thread, NULL); // <--- will wait for thread
```

Then it will probably work as you expect.

Another approach would be to terminate the main thread with pthread_exit() and then let the child continue, but that would be a really bad design. It actually leaves the pid as "defunct" on my system even though the child thread seems to continue to execute. It is a bad design for other reasons as well.

Comment: this is not the issue, read comment by Art in Question's Comment section.

Comment: @WaseemAhmadNaeem: The call to `pthread_join` prevents the main thread from exiting before the child thread finishes. That solves the problem identified by Art.

Comment: @WaseemAhmadNaeem:: As Jim Mischel says, and also Art, you need to let the child run it's code before terminating the entire process, including the thread. pthread_join() lets the caller (main thread) wait for the child thread. Anyway there was a fault in my answer, which is now corrected.

Comment: Is there another way that parent will wait for threads without using `thead_join`. like waste some amount of time etc??? I'd be thankful

Comment: @WaseemAhmadNaeem: You can do just about anything while "waiting" for other threads to finish, calculate primes, just sleep or anything. But it is convenient to use pthread_join() if you have no other useful work to do as it returns exactly when the child finishes. Note that it is also possible to call pthread _join() long after the child has finished. (I did not see that you had set the child to "detached" at first. A detached thread cannot be joined, but I guess you discovered that)

Comment: Thank You All, It helped me a lot